# Display inner HTML with directives

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to show search results. When clicked on matched word I want to navigate to the page, where the word was found.
So my HTML from search services looks like:

```
<li> Consequat torquatos at his, aeterno intellegebat ea vel. <a class="highlight" (click)="openPage('pageId', 'elementId')">Lorem</a> ipsum dolor sit amet, te pro deserunt philosophia, est ex reque volutpat.</li>
```

The problem is, that if this is added as inner html into results page, the directives are obviously not compiled because of Angular 2 security. I searched for a solution. DynamicComponentLoader is deprecated. The suggested way is probably to create a component, but I have no clue how to do a component for this type of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComponentFactoryResolver` can be used instead of `DynamicComponentLoader` :

```js
export class Foo implements OnInit {
    // The search function should be passed as an input

    constructor(private viewRef: ViewContainerRef, private dcl: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
    ngOnInit(){
      let cmpRef: ComponentRef<Foo>=this.viewRef.createComponent(this.dcl.resolveComponentFactory(AutocompleteList));
    }
}
```

But I don't think you need to use it, actually. You should implement a pipe that split the text in an array of Object like this :

```
[
  {
    value:"foo",
    highlighted:false
  },
  {
    value:"bar",
    highlighted:true
  }
]
```

and then in your template do something like (the pipe I mentioned earlier is called `highlight` here):

```html
<li *ngFor="let res of results">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let result of res | highlight" [ngSwitch]="result.highlight">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="false">{{result.value}}</ng-container>
    <a *ngSwitchCase="true" class="highlight" (click)="openPage('pageId', 'elementId')">{{highlight.value}}</a>
  </ng-container>
</li>
```

this should produce your expected output...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will take a look on how to use DynamicComponent loader. Can you please update the snippet with how to bind the result component to ui? If I have an array of html strings with directives, how to process them to show them in ui with directives working.

Comment: this snippet bind the component to the current view (at the end). You cannot use directives dynamically. So you'd better create a component that will handle the list of results and instanciate this component dynamically next to the input (I guess it's an autocomplete).

the result-component should have 2 observable properties: "highlight" and "dataSource" as `@Input()` and you can access it from the `cmpRef` variable

Comment: It's not a autocomplete, it's full-text search and I need to point user from search result back into text.

Comment: I accept your answer although it doesn't solve my problem. Just Angular component orientation doesn't allow me to manipulate with complex data. The pipe is not a solution because it's not easy to split the search result and  as I understand even ComponentFactoryResolver doesn't allow to use directives.